# Current predicate configuration does not have any valid root items defined

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-unicorn

Being new to unicorn I'm facing an interesting problem.  Which raises a couple of questions. Number one is where can I review my predicate configuration?
Number two do I need to view this predicate configuration or is there some other way to resolving my valid root item. 
Thanks 
[image]

Comment: Do you have `serialization.config` file in your `App_Config\Include` folder?

Comment: Yes unfortunately I do.

Comment: There should be `<predicate>` tag inside it containing a list of `<include>` tags. Each of include tag contains a serialization root. You should also be able to see the whole `<unicorn>` section if you browse to `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` url.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try that. 
I'm also looking in the developer tab and it also gives me several options. Such as serialize item / serialize tree. Is it possible to use these as well to solve my problem?

Comment: Unicorn is for automated synchronization of Sitecore items between environments. Manual serialization is much more limited.

Comment: Actually @marek, Unicorn3 replaces the in-client serialization commands

Comment: Looking at the image attached, it's Unicorn 2.0.4 ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Kamsars slightly unusual use of the word predicate; "Logic. that which is affirmed or denied concerning the subject of a proposition." might not be helping much either ;-)

Anyway. Unicorn 3 does come with a number of .config files, but as far as I can tell, no predicates are defined by default.

Look in App_Config\Include\Unicorn and find "Unicorn.Configs.Default.example". You can probably just remove the .example extension and fire up Unicorn with the default settings - that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue recently and after spending around 2 hours found that Serialization folders was empty (No Serialization files was present under folder) for features and foundation projects.

After copying serializations files in features and foundations it start working for me.